# Move the marker on Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am doing a tracking system. 
I am using codeigniter framework and mongodb connection.
Also I am using Google map javascript api v3 to load the map. 
I was able to load the marker on map. But I don't know how to move marker when values are loading from the database. I have read that I have to use AJAX to do it but have no idea.

I followed [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) to load the marker.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @GPRathour `I was able to load the marker on map. But I don't know how to move marker when values are loading from the database`

Comment: Move marker means? Are you trying to say, how to draw markers according to the values from Database?

Comment: I wanted to do something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/bmSbU/154/
But I want to load the values from database. (latitude and longitude)

Comment: Downvoted.. way too broad a question.. it covers all sorts of architectural questions.. but.. Moving a marker is covered by the API documentation for "setPosition". https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Answer (score 0):

There will be no change in the code of Google Maps, Let me give you a simple example of the same.

```
function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
        ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
    ];

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
        '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
        '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
        '</div>']
    ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}
```

So you just need to replace the values in markers array with the values you get from database and all markers will be drawn.

What you need to do is, fetch data from database in PHP.

```
<?php

        #code to fetch data from database
        #store results in array

        $lat_long_values = array
                               (
                                  array('London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562),
                                  array('Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755),
                              );
?>
```

Suppose you got values like that in an Array. Now use the values from this array in JavaScript. Therefore markers will now become,

`var markers = <?php echo $lat_long_values; ?>`

**Edit**

Then in that case, I would suggest you to use a combination of
[Ajax Get Method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

And [JavaScript `setInterval method`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
setInterval(function(){


    $.get( "YOUR_PHP_PAGE", function( data ) {
        //Do what you want with data
        alert(data);
    });


}, 3000);
```

You can see, I am calling the JS function after 3 seconds (3000 milli seconds) and in that I am calling the PHP function to fetch latest values from database.

You can apply this trick to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code you want..

```
$query = "select * from  table";
$result= mysql_query($query);
$lat[] = array();
$lng[]=array();
$x=0;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $lat[$x]=$rows['X'];
    $lng[$x]=$rows['Y'];
    $x++;

}//here is your connection in db

var markersdata=[];
function dd()
{

    latLocation =<?php echo json_encode($lat); ?>;
    lngLocation =<?php echo json_encode($lng); ?>;

            for (var i = 0; i < latLocation.length; i++) {
        //

                    makeMarker(latLoc[i],lngLoc[i]);


            }

}
funtion makeMarker(lati, longi)
{

   var markerOptions = {map: map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi)};`
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);`

}
//this code is working. leave comment if you have any question
```

Comment: just put the code of creating map and call the function dd after that. hope this will help

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a  question. where do I put the code snippet for "db connection"? Is it inside the body tag of the view file? because what I understood is, it must be called again and again to get the latest coordinates.

Comment: put it inside the body and it will query the db automatically